# Center floated divs

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with centering container with floated divs.
Here is my html:

```
<section class="bright front slider">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="title hidden-xs">
            Profesjonalna<br/>paltforma<br/>ankietowa
        </div>
        <div class="home-blocks">
            <div class="blocks size-sm">
                <a href="" class="block vertical orange offset-2 bordered hovered">
                    <div class="content left"><div class="border"><div class="text no-margin"><h3 class="white">Badania</h3></div></div></div>
                    <div class="content right" style="background: url(images/bg-orange.png) repeat, url(images/tile-img2.png) no-repeat left top;"><div class="border"></div></div>
                    <div class="hover orange"><div class="ht">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer sit amet tincidunt velit. Nunc viverra bibendum nibh et efficitur.</div></div>
                </a>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <a href="" class="block vertical green offset-1 bordered hovered">
                    <div class="content left"><div class="border"><div class="text no-margin"><h3 class="white">Wdrożenia</h3></div></div></div>
                    <div class="content right" style="background: url(images/bg-green.png) repeat, url(images/tile-img1.png) no-repeat left top;"><div class="border"></div></div>
                    <div class="hover green"><div class="ht">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer sit amet tincidunt velit. Nunc viverra bibendum nibh et efficitur.</div></div>
                </a>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <a href="" class="block vertical blue bordered hovered">
                    <div class="content left"><div class="border"><div class="text no-margin"><h3 class="white">Wsparcie</h3></div></div></div>
                    <div class="content right" style="background: url(images/bg-blue.png) repeat, url(images/tile-img4.png) no-repeat left top;"><div class="border"></div></div>
                    <div class="hover blue"><div class="ht">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer sit amet tincidunt velit. Nunc viverra bibendum nibh et efficitur.</div></div>
                </a>
                <a href="" class="block vertical red bordered hovered">
                    <div class="content left"><div class="border"><div class="text no-margin"><h3 class="white">Szkolenia</h3></div></div></div>
                    <div class="content right" style="background: url(images/bg-red.png) repeat, url(images/tile-img3.png) no-repeat left top;"><div class="border"></div></div>
                    <div class="hover red"><div class="ht">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer sit amet tincidunt velit. Nunc viverra bibendum nibh et efficitur.</div></div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I wont put the css code for it becouse its 500 lines in less(and i don't want to put selected fragments of it), I say only that each block may look like that in the end

```
.block{
   display: inline-block;
   float: left;
   overflow:hidden;
   width: 360px;
   height: 130px;
}
```

I use bootstrap in my project. And I need to use float for the elements to perfectly fit to each other.

How it look now:
[image]

I think I don't need to explain what effect i want.

Comment: If you are using bootstrap then you can manage your flow with row class and col-sm-12 combination of these

Answer (score 0):

Check with this css

```
.home-blocks
{
text-align:center;
}

.block{
   display: inline-block;
   overflow:hidden;
   width: 360px;
   height: 130px;
  text-align:center;
}

And for aligning images in center you must have to give this css for images in bootstrap
img {
  display: inline-block;
}
```